# Как инвертировать регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка. Я хочу вытащить регуляркой последние 7 символов, делаю это так: `.{7}$`.

Вопрос, как инвертировать эту регулярку, чтобы она выделяла все, кроме этих 7 последних символов?

Comment: А зачем в данном случае регулярка? Или это просто спортивный интерес?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с положительной опережающей проверкой (positive lookahead):

```
^.*(?=.{7}$)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с отрицательной ретроспективной проверкой (negative lookbehind):

```
^.+(?<!(?!.{7}$))
```